# Alterar o acionamento de click de um UISegmentedControl dentro de um UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou precisando alterar o acionamento de um `UISegmentedControl`, pois tenho um formulário, com vários `UISegmentedControl`, contidos em um `UIScrollView` e quando eu faço rolagem tocando em cima de um `UISegmentedControl` ele seleciona um dos valores.

Gostaria que não fosse selecionado. Tem como alterar esse comportamento? O `UISegmentedControl` consegue verificar se eu estou descendo, subindo ou pressionando a tela para que o elemento não seja selecionado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, teoricamente ele não deveria selecionar se você estiver realizando um movimento de rolagem no seu `UIScrollView`. Antes de qualquer coisa, certifique-se que o `UISegmentedControl` realmente está dentro do `UIScrollView` e não por baixo ou por cima.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer para tentar solucionar esse problema, que vai funcionar dependendo do cenário geral do seu `UIViewController`, é setar a propriedade `exclusiveTouch` do `UISegmentedControl` para `NO`. Dessa forma o toque será repassado também para o `UIScrollView` que vai continuar permitindo o movimento de rolagem.

Se nada disso funcionar para você, uma solução que pode ser utilizada é de desativar o `UISegmentedControl` enquanto o `UIScrollView` estiver sendo movimentado. Para aplicar tal solução você precisa assinar o delegate do `UIScrollView` (`UIScrollViewDelegate`) e implementar os métodos desejados (inicio e fim da rolagem). Basta definir a propriedade `enabled` do `UIScrollView` para `YES` e `NO` dentro de cada callback do delegate.